# Deploying a static website loads old version

Tags: docker, nginx

I am deploying a static website using the tutorial https://typeofnan.dev/how-to-serve-a-static-app-with-nginx-in-docker/
But my site always serves old version so I changed the build command to

```
docker build --no-cache --pull -t static-nginx
```

Still I am able to get only old version site

How can we fix that?
I amnew to docker and nginx

Comment: `docker build` is just building the image. Are you running it as well using `docker run` ?

Comment: How are you starting the container?  There's a recipe I see occasionally that uses Docker named volumes to try to publish static content to a reverse proxy, but that recipe has exactly the side effect you describe here: the volume content never gets updated and takes precedence over what's in the image.